# Limit number of threads in IMagick (PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

When using ImageMagick, I can set certain limits for memory usage and maximum number of threads. There are 3 ways to do this, as far as I know:

1. use a command line options like "convert -limit memory 128mb original.jpg new.jpg"
2. use environment variables like "MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1"
3. edit the 'policy.xml' configuration file to change the default value.

I have tested each of these methods using "convert -list resource" and they work.

Now, I need to use the IMagick extension in PHP. There is a function I can use to set limits:

```
bool Imagick::setResourceLimit (int $type, int $limit)
```

For the first parameter I can use one of the following:

```
imagick::RESOURCETYPE_AREA (integer)   //equivalent of MAGICK_AREA_LIMIT
imagick::RESOURCETYPE_DISK (integer)   //equivalent of MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT
imagick::RESOURCETYPE_FILE (integer)   //equivalent of MAGICK_FILE_LIMIT
imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MAP (integer)    //equivalent of MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT
imagick::RESOURCETYPE_MEMORY (integer) //equivalent of MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT
```

The problem is that there is no equivalent for MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT and IMagick seems to simply ignore the configuration files and the environment variables. How do I know this? I've set all the memory limits to zero and IMagick still functions without any problem when it should report insufficient memory.

I really hope I have made myself clear.
The question is: how can I change the thread limit when using IMagick?

EDIT:
I've managed to set the thread limit to 1 by compiling ImageMagick with the '--without-threads' option. :P It will have to do until I find a better solution.

Comment: Did you try using a small, non-zero value for the memory limits as well? (eg., 1)  There didn't seem to be any documentation on the setResourceLimit method and it may use 0 as unlimited, or 0 could be ignored and a default used when imagemagick is invoked.

Comment: If I set the limits using $image->setResourceLimit to zero, IMagick gives me errors about insufficient memory. I'm pretty sure this disables them because, for example, you can disable the disk memory.

Comment: I understand that setting the memory resource limit is simply how much RAM is uses -- if it needs more, it will use its own disk-based swap file for the rest.

Answer (score 6):

This helped:

```
Imagick::setResourceLimit (6, 1);
```

Comment: how to set in windows server/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pass the MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT environment variable to PHP interpreter so you don't need to touch the ImageMagick code.

Check this out: [High CPU load when converting images with ImageMagick](http://www.daniloaz.com/en/617/systems/high-cpu-load-when-converting-images-with-imagemagick/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding constant defined for the thread limit in the PHP IMagick extension, but looking at the source the integer value should be 6 so you could try that (see ResourceType in magick/resource_.h, the needed value is ThreadResource).  Am using MagickWand for PHP and had the same issue--fix was to enable this constant and recompile.  If you are interested in patching MagickWand for PHP 1.0.8 the fix is:

```
magickwand_inc.h
-#define PRV_IS_ResourceType( x ) (x == AreaResource || x == DiskResource || x == FileResource || x == MapResource || x == MemoryResource)  /* || x == UndefinedResource */
+#define PRV_IS_ResourceType( x ) (x == AreaResource || x == DiskResource || x == FileResource || x == MapResource || x == MemoryResource || x == ThreadResource)  /* || x == UndefinedResource */

magickwand.c
    MW_REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT( MemoryResource );
+   MW_REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT( ThreadResource );
```

Comment: Thanks! Right now I'm using ImageMagick compiled with the '--without-threads' flag and it also did the trick. I don't know why but ImageMagick runs 2-3 times slower on my VPS if it's compiled to use threads.

Answer (score 1):

At ImageMagick version 6.8.7-4, setResourceLimit(6,1) doesn't help, neither 
MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1.

But this setting does the trick:

```
OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1
```

In CLI:

```
env OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 php ./myscript.php
```

Comment: how to set in windows server